# Making io program more modular

Tags: haskell, menu, io

I am attempting to make a program that let's a user manipulate a database (a text file).

In the code I am posting, I show only 2 of the menu choices, namely "createdb" and "deletedb", and a few functions I made to desperately make the functions more compact. But my problem is that the pattern is similiar for all the other menu options. I ask the user to either enter the name of the database or "b" to return to the menu, and then check if the file exists.

Is there a way I can easily separate this to make my code more compact? I tried to do this part in the menu and have the choice functions be of type

```
FilePath -> IO ()
```

But then my menu looked really terrible. Here is a small part of the code:

```
type Choice = (String, String, IO ())

choices :: [Choice]
choices =
    [("a", "create a database", createdb),
    ("b", "delete a database", deletedb),
    ("c", "insert an entry to a database", insert),
    ("d", "print a database", selectall),
    ("e", "select entries from a database", select),
    -- more similiar choices

menu :: IO ()
menu = do
    (mapM_ putStrLn . map showChoice) choices
    c <- get "Enter the letter corresonding to the action of choice:"
    case filter ((== c) . fst3) choices of
    [] -> back "Not a valid choice. Try again"
    (_, _, f) : _ -> f


createdb :: IO ()
createdb = do
    n <- maybeName
    if isNothing n then menu else do
    let name = fromJust n
    fp <- maybeFile name
    if isJust fp
    then back $ "Error: \"" ++ name ++ "\" already exist." 
    else do
        cols <- get "Enter unique column names in the form n1,n2,...,n (No spaces):"
        let spl = (splitOnComma . toLower') cols
        case filter (== True) (hasDuplicates spl : map (elem ' ') spl) of
            [] -> writeFile (name ++ ".txt") (cols ++ "\n")
            _  -> back "Error: Column names must be unique and have no spaces."

deletedb :: IO ()
deletedb = do
    n <- maybeName
    if isNothing n then menu else do
        let name = fromJust n
        fp <- maybeFile name
        if isJust fp
        then removeFile (fromJust fp) 
        else back $ "Error: Could not find " ++ name

maybeName :: IO (Maybe String)
maybeName = do
    input <- get "Enter database name or 'b' to go back to the menu."
    return $ case input of
        "b" -> Nothing
        _   -> Just input 

maybeFile :: String -> IO (Maybe FilePath)
maybeFile name = do
    let fn = name ++ ".txt"
    exists <- doesFileExist fn
    return $ if exists then Just fn else Nothing

back :: String -> IO ()
back msg = do
    putStrLn msg
    menu

get :: String -> IO String
get msg = do
    putStrLn msg
    getLine
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for your question.

Comment: thank you! @MasterMastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [Exception monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html).

An example of how you might use it:

```
import Control.Monad.Except

data ExitType = ToMenu | Error String

deletedb :: ExceptT ExitType IO ()
deletedb = do
    name <- getName
    fp <- getFile name
    liftIO $ removeFile fp
```

(or even the equivalent one-liner `deletedb = liftIO . removeFile =<< getFile =<< getName` !)

Then you can do better exit handling in `getName` etc:

```
getName :: ExceptT ExitType IO String
getName = do
    input <- liftIO $ get "Enter database name or 'b' to go back to the menu."
    case input of
        "b" -> throwError ToMenu
        _   -> return input
```

A small example of running it:

```
menu :: IO ()
menu = do
    let action = deletedb -- display menu here to choose action
    r <- runExcept action
    case r of
        Left ToMenu         -> menu
        Left (Error errmsg) -> putStrLn errmsg >> menu
        Right result        -> print result
```